# CloudFormation not able to launch ECS Service

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

During a Buildkite pipeline running overnight, CloudFormation fails to create an ECS Service, timing out.

What could be the cause of the timeout?

**CFN Logs**

```
cfn INFO 03:08:51   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  build-amis-564-registrations: User Initiated
cfn INFO 03:08:56   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  TaskDefinition
cfn INFO 03:08:59   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  TaskDefinition: Resource creation Initiated
cfn INFO 03:08:59   CREATE_COMPLETE TaskDefinition
cfn INFO 03:09:02   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  ECSService
ecs INFO 03:09:10   Waiting for cluster to scale up. Please wait...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".buildkite/scripts/deploy/ecs_deploy.py", line 282, in <module>
    main()
  File ".buildkite/scripts/deploy/ecs_deploy.py", line 232, in main
    ecs.wait_for_service_steady(cluster, stack_name, project_name, desired_count)
  File "/app/ecs/__init__.py", line 680, in wait_for_service_steady
    raise Exception("Timed out waiting for service deployment")
Exception: Timed out waiting for service deployment
```

**Python script**

Excerpt from the python script generating the error after 15 minutes (CloudFormation itself goes on to timeout after three hours of unsuccessfully trying to create the service).

```
...
            for event in filter_events_response(response, last_event_id) or []:
                if "insufficient memory" in event["message"]:
                    message = info("Waiting for cluster to scale up. Please wait...")
                else:
                    message = event["message"]

                if log_progress:
                    logger.info(
                        "%s\t%s", event["createdAt"].strftime("%H:%M:%S"), message
                    )

                last_event_id = event["id"]
                waited = 0

                if "steady" in event["message"]:
                    logger.debug(event)
                    return

                if "deregistered" in event["message"]:
                    killed_tasks += 1

                    if killed_tasks > allowed_killed_tasks:
                        raise ServiceUnstableException(
                            "%s-%s service tasks are failing to start"
                            % (stack, service)
                        )

            time.sleep(20)
            waited += 20
            if waited > 900:
                raise Exception("Timed out waiting for service deployment")
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: deleting previously created CloudFormation stacks.

Once all the stacks previously created by the Buildkite pipeline were cleared out, the pipeline ran without error.

Best advice is to add a step in your pipeline to delete all stacks in the event of a failure to build them all.